# relational mysql query problem

Tags: php, mysql

Hy,

I'm new to mysql joins ... and i can't figure the logic now ...

I have a table : `attributes`

```
(1, 'display')
(2, 'processor')
(3, 'size')
```

and another table : `products`

```
(id, product_id, group, name, link_id)
(1, '12', display, Color, 0)
(2, '12', display, Resolution, 0)
(3, '12', display, Size, 0)
(4, '13', display, Color, 1) - this is the link_id (it holds the id of the same group of another product)
(5, '13', processor, 'Cache', 0)
... etc
```

So i want to build an ajax that when admin select the product category the script verify if it has a liked group to restrict adding fields to that group .

So basically ... i need to have a query to return :

```
(2, processor)
(3, size)
```

when user wants to alter attributes for product with id = 13 (because `display` group is used as a link)

Comment: This seems to be mixed a little here. What you've posted for `products` seems indeed to be the `attributes` and vice versa. So `Color` etc. are attributes, right? And display is a product? Please correct and also post your DDL to create these tables.

Comment: in the "group" column you should be referencing the attributes id, not the name.  also, having a "id" and "product_id" in the products table is confusing to say the least.  the design could stand a bit more work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a.id, a.name
from products p
left join attributes a on a.name=p.name
where p.product_id=X;
```

In this case X would be 13